# create AsyncTask to retrive object then pass it to BaseAdapter

Tags: android, listview, memory-leaks, android-asynctask

I retrieve Object from internet but when pass it directly to the BaseAdapter the Scrolling ListView is very slow and not smoothly.
In the following I had asked this question:

[List view crashes when scrolling "The application may be doing too much work on its main thread."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17892681/list-view-crashes-when-scrolling-and-doesnt-scroll-smoothly)

I want to ask how can create AsyncTask to retrieve data and pass it to the adapter
to make it faster and scrolling smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Do as this example

to execute task

```
new LongOperation().execute("");
```

and the task is like this.

```
private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

          @Override
          protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                return "Executed";
          }      

          @Override
          protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
                txt.setText("Executed"); // txt.setText(result);
                //might want to change "executed" for the returned string passed into onPostExecute() but that is upto you
          }

          @Override
          protected void onPreExecute() {
          }

          @Override
          protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
          }
    }
```

DoinBackground method is where you are doing your downloading data from server. and on postexecute assign that data to base adapter. and mind one thing is that you can't update views from DoinBackground method. you can have to use UIThread for changing Views.

Hope it Helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to download data in AsyncTask before you create your adapter and set it to ListView.

But nevertheless if you need to download data when your ListView is already created, then you, as **@Arman Stranger** said before you need to implement all work functions inside **doInbackgound()**.

F.e. when you have downloaded picture you should resize it to smaller size and execute **notifyDataSetChanged()** to redraw your listview.